# jquery .text doesn't render HTML elements into the DOM

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am loading a list of images into a div with the following bit of jQuery :

```
                var jewellerDdl = "<%= JewellerDropDownList.ClientID %>";
                var filter = $("#" + jewellerDdl).val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "popup.aspx/GetJewellerAssets",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: '{"jewellerId":' + filter + '}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: AjaxSucceeded,
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });

                function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
                    $("#divEntryDisplay").text(result.d);
                }

                function AjaxFailed(result) {
                    alert(result.status + ' - ' + result.statusText);
                }
```

The string I get back is a `<ul>` containing a few images

However, the .text method doesnt add them to the dom. Instead it just prints the HTML as text inside the `<div>` called divEntryDisplay

What have I done wrong?

Comment: text is for text. html is for html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should indeed use the html method (cf. documentation here : http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html)

Which makes your function look like this:

```
 function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
    $("#divEntryDisplay").html(result.d);
 }
```

Comment: OK, thanks, the example I was following said to use .text
http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Yes, in that case that's OK since they just need to update the div content with text only (no html).

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$("#divEntryDisplay").html(result.d);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insert HTML code into the DOM, then you must use the `html()` method, not the `text()` method.