# jQuery .text() Not Showing HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery .text doesn’t render HTML elements into the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764049/jquery-text-doesnt-render-html-elements-into-the-dom)

I have an AJAX function pulling an `<img>` tag from the server. My problem is, when I set the `.text()` property of a `span` on the page to that `<img>` tag, the HTML is not rendered. Rather, it just displays the tag as text.

Here is my code:

```
// jQuery
$.ajax({
  url: 'forms/scripts/getStatus.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
      subfolderID:rowID
  },
  async: false,
  success: function(data){
      if(data.errorsExist == "Y"){
          alert(data.appError);
      }
      else{
          $("#trackStatus").text(data.status);    
      } 
  },
  error: function(){
      alert("Error! Could not retrieve tracking status");
  }
});
```

My HTML:

```
<td><span id="trackStatus"></span></td>
```

How can I get the `img` tag to render as HTML? Maybe I shouldn't be using a `span` with the `.text()` method...?

Comment: That's not very surprising, it's described in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2. I recommend to read the documentation *before* you use a function, it might save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the help AND the -1 :)

Comment: I guess it's not acceptable (without getting downvoted) to miss something in the documentation. My mistake people!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use  `.html()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: Thanks. Quick and simple answer

Answer (score 2):

`.text()` escapes HTML. `.html()` does not, so use `.html()`.

Answer (score 1):

That's the purpose of the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text) function :

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML.

Use the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function instead  :

```
$("#trackStatus").html(data.status);
```